# How to Ignore Certain terms in search using Fusejs?

Tags: javascript, performance, fuse.js

I want to create a search using [fusejs](https://fusejs.io/), in which an entity or keyword can have multiple names, (alias). In [fusejs](https://fusejs.io/) the score is calculated based on the user input, he/she can enter any of the names. 
In my data i can have only 1 name.
For Example: "House"

```
[
     {"label": "House No. 436, Street 12, Phase 3"}
]
```

If a user enter "house" it works perfectly, but what if user enter Plot no, or home no, apartment no , flat no or any such word. In that case the score calculated will effect the search results. 
Please let me know if there is any way out for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a new array containing all the alias to each object.

```
[{"label": "House No. 436, Street 12, Phase 3", tags: ["Plot No", "Flat no", "Apartment no"]}]
```

and so on. And then i applied the weighted search with 0.7 weight to the variable `label` and 0.3 to array of alias.

```
 keys: [{
            name: 'tags',
            weight: 0.3
        }, {
            name: 'label',
            weight: 0.7
        }]
    };
```

Now if user inputs any of the keyword, it will have same impact, Thus the actual search results are not effected.